# Balsamiq on Stack Overflow

Tags: support

I've seen that a UI mockup tool is available on Stack Exchange site *[User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tour)* . I do not seem to find that on Stack Overflow (I can only see buttons to add a link, quote, and code picture), where some questions would be better if the asker could show the result they are looking for or what they are erroneously getting.

Is there a way to add such a UI mockup to other Stack Exchange sites besides *User Experience*? For example, could I write the question on *User Experience* and copy the markup to Stack Overflow (before submiting it to *User Experience*)? or is the UI mockup handler not available at all on Stack Overflow (as opposed to the button to open the tool not visible on Stack Overflow)?

P.S.: What would happen to a question migrated from *User Experience* to Stack Overflow?

Comment: In most cases I'm annoyed when users on SO post pictures instead of non-pictures.  Usually it's pictures of code that should be pictures of text, or pictures of their data that should be text, or pictures of error messages instead of the error message text.  I've found it *very* rare for SO questions to benefit from a screenshot.

Comment: I think one problem is, where does it end? For example, I'd **love** to see something like [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) as an available plugin on SO. It would make drawing control-flow diagrams, etc, crazy-simple. Others would like to see MathJax, etc. Since each one would only be relevant to a small-ish portion of SO in general, it's easier to just deny them all.

Comment: @GenericHolidayName or [tag:chess] programs that can't use [the Chess.SE special markup](http://chess.stackexchange.com/q/2281)?  Its no fair!

Comment: I think I'll have to clarify my question, and separate it from "would it be good for questions to have all the plugins available"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tool appears on UX as [a collaborative effort](http://blogs.balsamiq.com/product/2012/02/27/uxstackexchange/) between Stack Exchange and Balsamiq Studios. Given the focus of User Experience Stack Exchange, it makes sense to have such a tool there; although UX design questions do come up on Stack Overflow, they're a relatively small part of the site.

That said, if a question containing such mockups were migrated from UX to SO, the images would still appear - however, it would not be possible to edit them on Stack Overflow. For details, see: [Can StackExchange license Balsamiq for mockups on UX.Stackexchange?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/647/can-stackexchange-license-balsamiq-for-mockups-on-ux-stackexchange/781#781)